# Return the address of a global string variable

Tags: c, pointers, memory-address

How do I return the address of a global char* variable? I have to do this for a project. I have to write the function based on pseudo code which looks like this:

```
string* get_variable_address();
```

C doesn't have string so I assume `string*` will become `char**`. I've tried many things but I can't get it to work. What I have looks something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

char test[100] = "Get my address";

int main(void) {
    char** address = return_variable_address();

    printf("The address is: %s\n", *address);

    return 0;
}

char** return_variable_address() {
    return &test;
}
```

Comment: Is this from that CS-50 nonsense tutorial again?

Comment: `%s` is format for string, you want to use `%p` if you want to print a pointer value

Comment: Why not `char * test = "Get my address"` instead of `char test[100] = "Get my address"`?

Comment: @Lundin No, it's not. It's an Intel SGX project. The goal is to show how problematic enclave code can still allow attackers to retrieve the secrets of the enclave.

Comment: The problem is that address of an array is the address of the first element. You need to declare test as `char *test = "Get my address";`

Comment: @i486 Does it matter? Aren't they interchangeable? Doing it this way seemed more appropriate since the maximum size in my application is a constant so I can just do `char test[MAX_SIZE] = ...".

Comment: @ThomasVanhelden It matters because arrays are different from pointers in a few aspects. This being one.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya The thing is that I need to be able to change `test` afterwards. I can't do that on a `char*`.

Comment: @ThomasVanhelden I will add an answer that will let you do just that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> C doesn't have string so I assume string* will become char**

Probably not. A string in a C is a character array, which you can access through a `char*`. Therefore you can simplify your program quite a bit to get the desired result:

```
#include <stdio.h>

char* return_variable_address (void);

char test[100] = "Get my address";

int main(void) {
    char* address = return_variable_address();

    printf("The content stored at the address: %s\n", address);

    return 0;
}

char* return_variable_address (void) {
    return test;
}
```

Please note that all of this is bad practice - avoid global variables.

Comment: I think the OP needs to return the address of test not it's value, or I have misunderstood the question

Comment: Changing `%s` to `%p` in the `printf` and `return test` to `return &test` seems to do the job!

Comment: @ThomasVanhelden If you want to print the address, use `%p`. If you want to print the contents (of a string), use `%s`. I wasn't sure what you wanted to so I changed the printf text instead.

Answer (score 1):

Keeping your following requirements in mind -

1. You want to return a char** where one deferencing once gives you the string "Get my address"
2. You want the string to be mutable.

So you can do

```
char test[100] = "Get my address";

char *pointer = test;

char** return_variable_address(void) {
    return &pointer;
}

int main(void) {
    char** address = return_variable_address();
    printf("The address is: %s\n", *address);
    (*address)[0] = 'F'; //Test for mutability
    printf("The address is: %s\n", *address);
    return 0;
}
```

I understand that these requirements are for some security testing and hence are so peculiar.

Demo here: [Ideone](https://ideone.com/NDBMNI)

Comment: I don't think returning a char** is a requirement, the OP is merely confused over the meaning of the pseudo code (which I would be too).

Comment: @Lundin yes, that is probable. Either way, whatever works for OP.

Comment: This seems to work for me! Yes, I might be confused over the meaning of pseudo code. Because the assignment also says `"When required for security purposes (or C limitations), you may slightly modify the entry-point signatures"` So maybe, having a `char**` is not a hard requirement. All I really need is a function that returns the address of the global `char*` variable.

Comment: @ThomasVanhelden address of `char*` is again `char**`. You are confusing your self. Maybe you mean - All I really need is a function that returns the global char* variable

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya Maybe I am confused. Though, I am sure that I need a function that returns the address of the global variable. I'll try to give you some more background on the requirements. It's an Intel SGX project. The global variable is a password residing in a secure enclave. The goal is to show how unsafe enclave code (i.e. leaking an address) can give the attacker access to the secrets of the enclave.

Comment: You can return `test` if you want to return the address of the string, such that it can be read and modified with it. But I believe the memory in enclave is encrypted by the hardware. It will not be dereferencable from outside the enclave.

Answer (score 1):

It might help you to **typedef** a definition of **string**. Then it is easy to see that the address of a **string** variable **s** is just **&s** as for any other address. I expect that **string** is used a lot through the project and the typedef will also save you from trying to change every **string** to **char***.

To print an address use the format flag **%p**.

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef char string[10];    // string defined as an arrary of 10 chars

string s = "Hello world";   // I've deliberately put a common error in here

string* return_variable_address( void )
{
    return &s;
}

int main( void )
{
    printf("Address of global var s = %p \n", return_variable_address() );

    return 0;
}
```